# Radio inputs created with a loop in jQuery all being assigned the same value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

First time posting here. I am trying to make a movie recommender that presents the user with a set of movies to rate on a radio scale of 1-10 with a "No Rating" button if they haven't seen the movie. I have been trying to loop over all of the checked buttons to get their values, but they are all coming up as the value assigned to the first "No Rating" button in the radio input, which is appended to the table before the inner loop executes. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on? I don't have much experience in JS or jQuery and have had my brother helping me along the way. Here is my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
...
    let $movieRating = $('<tr class="rating-row">')
...
// Add initial "No Rating" button
    let $ratingButton = $('<td>');
    $ratingButton.append($(`<input type="radio" class="ratButton" id="rating${i}-0"
      name="rating${i}" value=null><label for="rating${i}-0">No Rating</label>`));
// Add 1-10 buttons   
    for (let j=1; j <= 10; j++) {
        $ratingButton.append($(`<input type="radio" class="ratButton" id="rating${i}-${j}"
          name="rating${i}" value="${j}"><label for="rating${i}-${j}">${j}</label>`));
    }
    $movieRating.append($ratingButton);
    $("table tbody").append($movieRating);
```

I have the value set to null for the "No Rating" button, and then the 1-10 buttons are supposed to have the value set to the ${j}. I am pulling the values with:

```
$('.rating-row').each(function(idx, row) {
    let $radioButton = $(row).find('input:radio');
    if ($radioButton.is(':checked')) {
        let radioVal = $radioButton.val();
         console.log(radioVal);
    }
})
```

radioVal is always coming up null, no matter what is checked. I hope this is clear. Tips on formatting welcome as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: CSS doesn't seem relevant here, and I'm not sure what HTML you need to help with this issue. It's a basic table, and all I've left out is the first header row. Is there something specific you need?

Comment: We always want enough code to produce a minimal executable version of your issue. IN your case, you have several variables that refer to HTML elements and several spots where you've just inserted `...` in leui of code.

Comment: Ahh, I see that in Vitalii's response. Will make sure to include enough to make it executable next time. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `$radioButton`.

```
let $radioButton = $(row).find('input:radio');
```

It contains not 1 but 11 radio buttons (each `rating-row` has 11 radio buttons added to it).

They should be iterated using `.each()` call as follows

```
let $radioButtons = $(row).find('input:radio');
$radioButtons.each(function (ind, radioButton){
  const $radioButton = $(radioButton);
  if ($radioButton.is(':checked')) {
    let radioVal = $radioButton.val();
    console.log(radioVal);
  }
})
```

Here's a working prototype:

```js
let keys = [0, 1, 2];
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let $movieRating = $('<tr class="rating-row">')
    let $ratingButton = $('<td>');
    $ratingButton.append($(`<input type="radio" class="ratButton" id="rating${i}-0"
name="rating${i}" value=null><label for="rating${i}-0">No Rating</label>`));
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        $ratingButton.append($(`<input type="radio" class="ratButton" id="rating${i}-${j}"
    name="rating${i}" value="${j}"><label for="rating${i}-${j}">${j}</label>`));
    }
    $movieRating.append($ratingButton);
    $("table tbody").append($movieRating);
}

$('#check').on('click', function () {
    $('.rating-row').each(function (idx, row) {
        let $radioButtons = $(row).find('input:radio');
        $radioButtons.each(function (ind, radioButton) {
            $radioButton = $(radioButton)
            if ($radioButton.is(':checked')) {
                let radioName = $radioButton.attr('name');
                let radioVal = $radioButton.val();
                console.log(radioName + ' = ' + radioVal);
            }
        })

    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```